# Why is the interpolation between two connections related via a gauge transformation still a connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory

I am studying the theory of anomalies in gauge field.

Let $A$ be a gauge field (or a connection for mathematicians). Let $A_{U}$ be an equivalent gauge related via a local gauge transformation 
$$A_{U}=U^{-1}dU+U^{-1}AU$$
Then, there is a interpolating between the two 
$$A(s)=sA+(1-s)A_{U}$$
where $s\in[0,1]$.

Why is $A(s)$ a connection? If $A$ is a flat connection, then this interpolation $A(s)$ between two flat connections isn't even flat. What are the geometric and physical meaning of such an interpolation?

Comment: Let's check the first condition:
For a fundamental vector field $\tilde{X}$, we get 
$A(s)(\tilde{X}) = sX +(1-s)X = X$ and the behavior under right 
translation can be checked the same way. Thus, unless I went horribly wrong,
$A(s)$ should be a connection form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The space of connections is affine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(principal_bundle)#Affine_property), so you can create convex combinations of connections.

If you think in terms of Ehresmann connections, you're dealing with projections onto the vertical bundle. If you substract two projections, you'll get an endomorphism that has a vertical image and annihilates vertical vectors. Such endomorphisms form the underlying vector space.

In more familiar language, take a Lie-algebra valued 1-form on your principal bundle that fullfills the same equivariance condition that connection forms fulfill, and is horizontal in the sense of annihilating vertical vectors (and in particular fundamental vector fields). [Such forms are called tensorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form#Basic_or_tensorial_forms_on_principal_bundles). If you add a tensorial form to a connection form, you get another connection form, and the difference between two connection forms will be tensorial.